# Ways to export 'WebAPI Help Page' into document

Tags: asp.net

I was wondering if there is any way we can conveniently export the auto-generated Help Pages of a WebAPI project into a document (Any format).

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use already available html-to-pdf converters?
Like http://pdfcrowd.com/

Comment: @matcheek hey, its still locally hosted atm. was wondering if there is a simple way to generate actually other than using 3rd party tools. Thanks

Comment: have you got any solution?